# Custom 3D touch and WkWebView issue

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, 3dtouch

I am trying to implement a custom peek/pop behaviour in WkWebView.
I see the delegate being called and the controller being returned, but peek controller does not showup.

I can only get the peek controller to showup by setting
self.webView?.userInteractionEnabled = false

What could be going on here?

Code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, UIViewControllerPreviewingDelegate {

var webView: WKWebView?

func webView(webView: WKWebView,
    decidePolicyForNavigationResponse navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,
    decisionHandler: ((WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)){

        decisionHandler(.Allow)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    /* Create our preferences on how the web page should be loaded */
    let preferences = WKPreferences()
    preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true

    /* Create a configuration for our preferences */
    let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    configuration.preferences = preferences

    /* Now instantiate the web view */
    webView = WKWebView(frame: view.bounds, configuration: configuration)

    if let theWebView = webView{
        /* Load a web page into our web view */
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com")
        let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        theWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
        theWebView.navigationDelegate = self
        view.addSubview(theWebView)

    }

    self.registerForPreviewingWithDelegate(self, sourceView: self.view)
}

func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, viewControllerForLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIViewController? {

    self.webView?.userInteractionEnabled = false
    let peekViewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("peekaboo") as UIViewController
    /*
    Set the height of the preview by setting the preferred content size of the detail view controller.
    Width should be zero, because it's not used in portrait.
    */
    peekViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)

    // Set the source rect to the cell frame, so surrounding elements are blurred.
    //previewingContext.sourceRect = (self.webkitWebView?.frame)!

    return peekViewController
}

/// Present the view controller for the "Pop" action.
func previewingContext(previewingContext: UIViewControllerPreviewing, commitViewController viewControllerToCommit: UIViewController) {
    // Reuse the "Peek" view controller for presentation.

}
}
```

Comment: I see that it is trying to load the controller but it never shows up....

Answer (score 0):

Set a prefferedContentSize height

```
peekViewController.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 150)
```